# How to avoid the button events on Refresh of page

Tags: asp.net, events, refresh

I have .aspx page that page inserts the data to the database on a button click. But when i press the button it is going right. i m getting the Successfully message as " successfully inserted data". In this situation if i press "F5" or Refresh the page it is firing the button click event. Why  it should be ? How to avoid this condition ?

Comment: can you add some code of yours??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the user clicks <kbd>F5</kbd> (or uses a toolbar button to refresh the page) it *will* cause a new request, identical to the previous one, to be sent to the server. The `Button.Click` event *will* be raised again, but you have a few ways to protect yourself against inserting the data twice.

The best way, IMHO, is to use the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). In your code, right after the point where the data is saved, do a 302 redirect to a confirmation page:

```
protected void btnSaveStuff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveStuffToDatabase();
    Response.Redirect("confirmation.aspx");
}
```

When using the pattern, the `POST` to the original page will not end up in the browser history, and refreshing the result page will cause the final `GET` to be repeated, which should be safe.

Comment: I read the article. but How to use GET/POST in master detail scenario then?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "master detail scenario". As shown in my code sample, you simply need to do a `Response.Redirect`, which will "cancel" then `POST` and make the browser to a fresh `GET`.

Comment: what if at the end of saving data some display message needs to be shown in this case answer from @Love-40 is the correct one

Comment: @xyz I would still prefer to "break" the POST by doing a redirect. If you want to display a confirmation screen, create this on a separate URL and redirect here from the POST.

Answer (score 4):

Add this  in your class:

```
#region Browser Refresh
private bool refreshState;
private bool isRefresh;

protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    object[] AllStates = (object[])savedState;
    base.LoadViewState(AllStates[0]);
    refreshState = bool.Parse(AllStates[1].ToString());
    if (Session["ISREFRESH"] != null && Session["ISREFRESH"] != "")
        isRefresh = (refreshState == (bool)Session["ISREFRESH"]);
}

protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    Session["ISREFRESH"] = refreshState;
    object[] AllStates = new object[3];
    AllStates[0] = base.SaveViewState();
    AllStates[1] = !(refreshState);
    return AllStates;
}

#endregion
```

And in your button click do this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isRefresh == false)
    {
        Insert Code here
```

Comment: good answer. would you mind if you explain your code here? Thanks

Comment: I assume that `LoadViewState` and `SaveViewState` need to be wired up to some event(s)?  Which ones and/or how do you do that?

Comment: nice! i put the code in my base page and used the if condition in the page where button click event is present. it worked nice! good job   +1 for u

Comment: i used your code, i face a problem, if my button click event is not Ajax then isrefresh is true on first button click, so if i click the button for second time Isrefresh is false and data is submitted to DB.

Answer (score 3):

Add a update panel and set the Update Mode of the update panel as Conditional.
This worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

The refresh will re-submit the form you posted last time when you clicked the button.

Usually, when you refresh a page you think of GETing the page again, or doing an HTTP GET, but since the last thing you did was a POST (when you clicked the submit button) the browser will perform the post again to attempt to invoke the same response.

I suggest using the Post/Redirect/Get pattern as suggested by [Jorn Schou-Rode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167490/how-to-avoid-the-button-events-on-refresh-of-page/2167498#2167498).

This article also seems relevant.
http://aspalliance.com/687_Preventing_Duplicate_Record_Insertion_on_Page_Refresh

Comment: I don't think TJB the second link that you provided is use full. I needs too much execution right? really code is good but not proper way. See If i have 100 pages so according to this article I need to code on each page with respective fields. Which is wrong. Is any other way ??please