# hit f5 or refresh button on page should not call last event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to insert image into database and after saving one image, I want to hit f5 or refresh buttton in browser, but the same image is inserted at that time please give me solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? https://www.google.com/search?q=prevent+postback+f5&oq=disable+F5+post&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.11451j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=prevent+postback+f5+asp.net

Comment: i have tried window.onunload function but i think it is not useful so

Comment: Googling can lead to a result : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASP.Net---Prevent-DuplicateDouble-Inserts-when-Page-is-refreshed.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot ankur  it is useful

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to protect yourself against inserting the data twice.

The best way is your data was stored then redirect to confirmation page , Like

```
protected void btnSavebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ItemsSaved();
    Response.Redirect("confirmation.aspx");
}
```

More details, see this [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167490/how-to-avoid-the-button-events-on-refresh-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to make redirect instead of posting content to the same site.
It would go something like this:

> Site with form -> post content -> site saving file -> site with form

Where I think you are doing something like:

> Site with form -> post content -> site with form